# MS Access - Multivalue Fields

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been creating a consumables database for machinery. My plan is so that each consumable or part is entered into the "tblParts" following this sort of structure; (**ForMachine** is combobox)

PartID ~ PartName ~ PartNumber ~ ForMachine
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 ~ O-Ring ~ 132-453 ~ Fan

2 ~ Blade ~ 352-281 ~ Saw

The machines will be listed in "tblMachines";

MachineID ~ MachineLocation ~ MachineName
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 ~ Upstairs ~ Fan

2 ~ Downstairs ~ Saw

The issue is that sometimes parts might be suited for more than one machine, and thus I had incorporated a multivalue combobox to accommodate for this in the parts table. However, when maintenance has been done on one of these machines and a part is used, I desire a form where the subtable only shows relevant parts for the machine selected and from there the user can select the desired item type a quantity and the database does the rest, like so;

[image: Example]

I have been able to achieve this when a consumable is only related to one machine (normal Combobox) via Master & Child Fields. However, when trailing this same technique using multiple values I receive the error message of "you cannot assign a multivalued or attachment field to the link master fields". This is the first time that I have touched multivalve fields and I am struggling to identify a work around for this.

How exactly, can I get it so that each consumable/part can be assigned to more than one machine, without duplicating the part over and over, yet still show in the subtable shown in the image above? The reason I want to steer clear of duplicating is due to every time a quantity is entered with the part, this then deducts that amount from the totals for that part allowing a clear understanding of stock/re-order levels.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One machine has many parts and one part can go into many machines, so what you need is a many-to-many table to list all the possible combinations. The table will only have two fields: the machine id and part numbers.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot where you get the error *"you cannot assign a multivalued or attachment field to the link master fields"*? Multivalue fields are, indeed, annoying, but with some patience and research you can dominate them. Notice that when you have a multivalue field, actually is like a "table" inside a field. When you use multivalue fields in queries, you have 2 options to add to your query. The normal field and a new field called *nameoffield.value". Use the second one and keep trying. I'm pretty sure what you want to do can be done.

Comment: Thank you both, I have had a play with the multivalues but in the end have gone with @jshorts advice as a many-to-many option is much easier to comprehend. Thank you again for your help!